# Split view is missing in Visual Studio

Tags: designer, visual-studio-2017

Something changed in my Visual Studio (2017) and now I don't have the option the view the design in Split view.
Only Design / XML

[image: Split view is missing]

Comment: are there button [<<] on the right side (tooltip Expand Pane)?

Answer (score 1):

You should press the **Expand Pane** button to get it back:

[image]

[image]